Pickle load to CPU of an internal model
lets state clearly my problem. I have a feature_extractor.pkl file that denotes a FeatureExtractor object which object has inside a BERT model like the following class
 class BERTFeatureExtractor:
    def __init__(self, pretrained_bert_model_name, process_fn, process_fn_kwargs=None):
        self.pretrained_bert_model_name = pretrained_bert_model_name
        self.process_fn = process_fn
        self.process_fn_kwargs = process_fn_kwargs if process_fn_kwargs is not None else {}

        # Load pre-trained BERT tokenizer and model
        print('IMMA USE', self.pretrained_bert_model_name)
        self.tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained(self.pretrained_bert_model_name)
        self.model = BertModel.from_pretrained(self.pretrained_bert_model_name)

        # Move model to GPU
        device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
        self.model.to(device)
        
        return
    
    def fit(self, df):
        return
    
    def transform(self, df, id_cols=None):
        device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
        start = time()

        texts = df['essay']

        if id_cols is not None:
            identifiers = df[id_cols]

        # Prepare BERT features for each document
        bert_features = []
        for text in tqdm(texts, desc='BERT Features'):
            encoded_input = self.tokenizer(text, return_tensors='pt', padding=True, truncation=True, max_length=512)

            # Move input tensors to GPU
            encoded_input = {key: value.to(device) for key, value in encoded_input.items()}
            
            with torch.no_grad():
                output = self.model(**encoded_input, output_hidden_states=True)

            embeddings = self.process_fn(output, **self.process_fn_kwargs).cpu().numpy()
            bert_features.append(embeddings)

        bert_feature_names = [f'BERT Feature {i + 1}' for i in
                            range(len(bert_features[0]))]
        bert_df = pd.DataFrame(bert_features, columns=bert_feature_names)

        if id_cols is not None:
            bert_df = pd.concat([identifiers, bert_df], axis=1)

        print('BERT finished after', time() - start, 'seconds')
        return bert_df #, self.model, self.tokenizer

    def fit_transform(self, df, id_cols=None):
        return self.transform(df, id_cols)

and when i load a model i get Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA device but torch.cuda.is_available() is False. If you are running on a CPU-only machine, please use torch.load with map_location=torch.device('cpu') to map your storages to the CPU.
Is there something I can do and load to cpu except recreating the pickle files?

Did you try passing map_location=torch.device('cpu') to torch.load like the error suggests?

I tried it but I still get the same error

    with open(artifact_uri, "rb") as f:         feature_set_extractor = torch.load(f, map_location=torch.device('cpkdjgokju')) # pickle.load(f)
